# Calculate value in array under certain condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I have array as below:

```
const array = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 8, 10, 13, 15];
```

I want to sum values less than 10 in the array to sum up and become more than 10 as below:

```
const newArray = [16, 20, 18, 13, 15]; // 16 at index 0 is from (1+3+5+7), 20 at index 1 is from (9+11), 18 at index 2 is from (8+10)
```

This is what I have attempted and I stuck from here:

```
const minTen = array.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
    
    if (currentValue < 10) {

        // 1. Sum value in array to become >= 10
        const accumValue = currentValue += // help here please or any othr alternative

        // 2. Push new value to the array
        accumulator.push(accumValue);
    }
    return accumulator;
}, []);

console.log(minTen); // [16, 20, 18, 13, 15]
```

Comment: edited. I tried to follow example "Replace filter().map() with .reduce()" in this documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check the last value of the result set.

```js
const
    array = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 8, 10, 13, 15],
    minTen = array.reduce((accu, value) => {
        if (accu[accu.length - 1] < 10) accu[accu.length - 1] += value;
        else accu.push(value);
        return accu;
    }, []);

console.log(minTen); // [25, 11, 18, 13, 15]
```

Comment: hi, i have latest edit with slightly different requirement. apologize for that

Comment: this works! do you mind explaining what does accu[accu.length - 1] actually do. or where i can find documentation on this. i just started learning javascript today with some python knowledge.

Comment: [`Array#length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) returns the length of the array. the part calculates the last index and gets the last element of the array.

Answer (score 2):

Steps:

1. Iterate through the given array and give it a condition - if the number is less than 10 then sum it up, else push it into a result array.
2. Insert the final sum in the first place of the result array.
3. Done

```js
const array = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15]

let sum = 0, resultArr = []
array.forEach(i => i<10 ? sum += i : resultArr.push(i))
resultArr = [sum, ...resultArr]
console.log(resultArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use Array.reduce :

```js
const array = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15];
let sum = 0;
const minTen = array.reduce((acc, currentValue) => {
        if (currentValue < 10) {
            sum += currentValue
        } else {
            acc = [...acc, currentValue]
        }
        return acc
}, []);

console.log([...minTen, sum]);
```

But I'm not sure it's the best method to use.

Comment: they do not make sense to me anymore. 
What is the rule for stopping the sum at (1+3+5+7) rather than (1, 3, 5, 7, 9) for example? 
Also is "lower than 10" or "lower or equal 10"?

Answer (score 0):

`array.reduce` is one of the modern functions that I don't prever to use. To be honest, I don't know how it works. And if DBS is correct, you don't either. So you can do it on the easy way.

```
for (var i=0, n=0, newArray = [];i<array.length;i++) {
    if (array[i] >= 10) {
        newArray.push(array[i]);
    } else {
        n += array[i];
    }
}
newArray.unshift(n);
```

Comment: Okay. That means the command `newArray.unshift(n)` must be placed before `newArray.push(array[i])` and `unshift` must be `push`. Behind that command you have to add `n = 0` to reset the variable.

Answer (score 0):

This uses the filter function to only add the ones that are bigger than 10 and sums the lower ones. At the end the sum will just be inserted at index 0 of the array by calling [Array.prototype.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```js
 const array = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15];
 
 let underTen = 0;
 const minTen = array.filter(val => {
     if (val < 10) {
        underTen += val;
     } else {
        return val;
     }
});

// add sum at pos 1
minTen.splice(0, 0, underTen);
console.log(minTen);
```

Answer (score 0):

I discourage doing 2 different operations, filter and sum, in the same function. A clean solution always do one thing at a time. Here the solution is presented in the context of an automatic unit test:

```js
test('62893326', () => {
  const input = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15]
  const expected = [25, 11, 13, 15]
  const lower = input.filter(i => i < 10)
  const higher = input.filter(i => i >= 10)
  const sum = lower.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue)
  const result = [sum, ...higher]
  expect(result).toEqual(expected)
})
```

Comment: Hi, I do not understand the requirements anymore. 
What is the rule why you aggregate and sum (1+3+5+7) rather than (1+3+5+7+9)? 
Also is "lower than 10" or "lower and equal 10"?

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting for a while, I have found that this code, which mostly uses raw operations rather than library functions, sums numbers in the initial array up to form values that are greater than 10 and stops summing as soon as the sum is 11 or greater:

```js
const array = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 8, 10, 13, 15];
 let sum = 0;
 let arrayLength = array.length;
for(var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    if (array[i] <= 10) {
        sum += array[i];
        let n = i+1;
        if (n < arrayLength) {
            do {
                sum += array[n];
                n++;
            }
            // keep adding numbers from the array until a sum of 11 or greater
        while((n) < arrayLength && array[n] <= 10 && sum < 11);
        }
        // replace the numbers in the array that were summed together
        // with the sum of those numbers.
        array.splice(i, n - i, sum);
        sum = 0; // reset for next iteration
    }
    // the for loop advances to the next position in the array automatically
}

console.log(array); // outputs [16, 20, 18, 13, 15]
```